# Windows won't check for updates, fails to update manually.

Tags: windows-7, windows, automation, windows-update, updates

Windows 7 Enterprise x64

I've had this problem for about a year now. Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation to post images directly on here yet, but I can link to screenshots I have uploaded to imgur:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7PUX.jpg

This album shows the extent of my problem—at first when I open the Windows Update center, it shows that I have no available updates. Then I click "Check online for updates from Windows Update," and suddenly it shows a dozen or so available. I click *Install updates* and it tries and fails to install all of the updates. The same updates typically fail each time, but if there are other new updates then they will usually work.

It keeps throwing error code *8024200D*. How do I make it check for updates without me prompting, and how do I get it to install these updates? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing this is your work computer.  Looking at your screenshots, I believe I see where your issue is coming from.  Look at the second screenshot you posted.  "You receive updates:  Managed by your system administrator"  There is a group policy set to manage your updates for you.  You need to contact your system administrator and see if you should even be applying updates manually.  And if there is a GP in place, why is it letting you install some items at all?